# Substitute word with same word without initial @ in R

Tags: r, string, symbols, gsub

I am trying to do a dataframe string substitution in R. I need to find all the words preceded by '@' (without space, e.g. @word) and change the '@' for '!' (e.g. from @word to !word). At the same time, it leaves intact the other instances of '@' (e.g. @ or @@ or @[@]). For example, this is my original dataframe (to change: @def, @jkl, @stu):

```
> df = data.frame(number = 1:4, text = c('abc @def ghi', '@jkl @ mno', '@[@] pqr @stu', 'vwx @@@ yz'))
> df
  number          text
1      1  abc @def ghi
2      2    @jkl @ mno
3      3 @[@] pqr @stu
4      4    vwx @@@ yz
```

And this is what I need it to look like:

```
> df_result = data.frame(number = 1:4, text = c('abc !def ghi', '!jkl @ mno', '@[@] pqr !stu', 'vwx @@@ yz'))
> df_result
  number          text
1      1  abc !def ghi
2      2    !jkl @ mno
3      3 @[@] pqr !stu
4      4    vwx @@@ yz
```

I have tried with

```
> gsub('@.+[a-z] ', '!', df$text)
[1] "abc !ghi"   "!@ mno"     "!@stu"      "vwx @@@ yz"
```

But the result is not the desired one. Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
gsub("(^| )@(\\w)", "\\1!\\2", df$text)
# [1] "abc !def ghi"  "!jkl @ mno"    "@[@] pqr !stu" "vwx @@@ yz"
```

This matches an `@` symbol at beginning of a string, or after a space.  Then, we capture the word character after the `@` symbol, and replace `@` with `!`.

Explanation courtesy of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/WCeIAQ/1):

- `(^| )` is the 1st Capturing Group; `^` asserts position at start of the string; `|` denotes "or"; blank space matches the space character  literally
- `@` matches the character `@` literally (case sensitive)
- `(\\w)` is the 2nd Capturing Group, it denotes a word character

The replacement string `\\1!\\2` replaces the regular expression match with the first capturing group (`\\1`), followed by `!`, followed by the second capturing group (`\\2`).

Comment: Hi Rich Scriven, thank you so much for both the solution and a very detailed explanation of the logic behind it. It works perfectly. Have a great day.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a positive lookahead `(?=...)`

```
gsub("@(?=[A-Za-z])", "!", df$text, perl = TRUE)
[1] "abc !def ghi"  "!jkl @ mno"    "@[@] pqr !stu" "vwx @@@ yz"
```

From the "Regular Expressions as used in R" documentation page:

> Patterns (?=...) and (?!...) are zero-width positive and negative lookahead assertions: they match if an attempt to match the ... forward from the current position would succeed (or not), but use up no characters in the string being processed.

Comment: Hi Sraffa, thank you very much for your answer and the explanation. Your solution works perfectly. Have a good day.